# Leaflet: Change popup behavior so that if popup is open, click outside popup will only close popup (not open new popup based on click location)?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

**Final Edit**

My thinking on this experience was for a web app targeting mobile use. On mobile, users often expect that a tap will dismiss the item. The most similar standard web experience would be clicking outside of a model (on the translucent overlay) to dismiss the modal (sort of an implicit Escape Key). This approach would work well on my map because then I can hide the close button the popup and the user would probably try either clicking the popup itself, or clicking off it, and both would close the popup.

For example, see this video of my project: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/SCyKfKbvfa8)

By default, popups are dismissed when clicking the basemap. But when zooming into the playground and clicking a marker, the entire viewable area of the map has an active polygon overlay, so clicking off of the popup fires a new popup. For a mobile experience, I think it'd be better to have the options to *just* close the open popup (as if you were clicking on the basemap), and require another tap to open a new one.

**Solution**

My solution was to move all popups to a pane with z index 700, and then create another pane at z 699 for a transparent overlay. Then I used the popupopen and popupclose events to add and remove a transparent polygon from the map at z699 which effectively block clicks to any layers down below until the user closes the current popup.

```
map.getPane('popupPane').style.zIndex = 700;
map.createPane('hiddenOverlay').style.zIndex = 699;

let hiddenData = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "overlay",
        "popupContent": "test"
        },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [-121.728602, 37.691681],
            [-121.724186, 37.691543],
            [-121.723973, 37.689516],
            [-121.728260, 37.689467]]]
     }
}];

let transparentStyle = {
    color: "#ff0b00",
    weight: 5,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    opacity: 0
};

let hiddenLayer = L.geoJSON(hiddenData, {
    pane: 'hiddenOverlay',
    style: transparentStyle
});


map.on('popupopen', function(e){
    map.addLayer(hiddenLayer);
});

map.on('popupclose', function(e){
    map.removeLayer(hiddenLayer);
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you think this would be a better experience for whoever is using your map? From personal experience if I click from one marker to the other, I would expect the "current behavior." I'd also recommend including your current working code and any photos you think will help the community understand and solve the issue. (It will also help avoid downvotes.)

Comment: @riastrad    Thanks, I understand why this was downvoted. I added some more explanation and an example video in the edit. Note sure there's much point in code since right now its just default popup code in my project.